# How to extract patterns that match regex in java

Tags: java, regex

I am working with regex in java. I have a file which contains the following pattern followed and preceded by other text. The pattern:

```
    Bombay Garden 5995 Mowry Ave Newark, CA (510) 744-6945   
    Bombay Garden 172 E. 3rd Ave. San Mateo, CA (650) 548-9966   
    Bombay Garden 3701 El Camino Real Santa Clara, CA (408) 241-5150
```

I have the following regex that matches each line. The regex:

```
(.*?)(\d{1,4})(\s*\w*)*(\w+),(\s*)(CA|AZ|NY)(\s*)(\(?[1-9]\d{2}\)?\s*\d{3}-?\d{4})
```

This matches one line, but i want to extract the street name, state and the phone number for each of the three branches using Java.

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You extract the contents of a capturing group by using `group()` of the `Matcher` object, and passing it a group number, ie:

```
  Matcher m = Pattern.compile(yourRegex).matcher(yourString)
  while (m.find()) 
  {
      System.out.println(m.group(1));
      System.out.println(m.group(2));
      String state = m.group(6);
      ...
  }
```

Group 0 is the entire pattern. Group 1 is your first capturing group, ie in your case `m.group(6)` will return the state.

Comment: @Nemin [Here's](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/) the oracle tutorial for regex in Java.  Good luck.